# What should I tell my web designer?

Tags: php, html, web

I hired a web developer and a web designer who are working on a *customized HTML & PHP based website*. The designer today emailed me a **sample image** of what he is creating for the front end(I think with adobe illustrator), which is the image at the bottom.

The issue here is when I showed this image to my web developer, he said *unless these images are written in html and css, he cannot use them.*

*As I am not an expert, I am not sure how to communicate with the designer. What should I ask him? What should I instruct him to do for the web developer?*

**Website mock design**

[image: Website mock design]

Comment: Designer should return the design in html and css

Comment: These images are probably a proof for you to sign off before the designer works on the HTML & CSS.

Comment: If the web developer is doing templating work as well (html,css), then designer should have send all the image assets, such as icons, image backgrounds etc. I think this design screenshot is just for you to see it an approve it, and then designer will prepare the assets.

Comment: Designer should give you a `.psd` and slice it to `png` or `jpg` images. then your developer should make it with `CSS` and `Html` . so first things first you need ask a  `.psd` file.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys. It helped a lot. I have a better idea on what to do now. What a wonderful community this website is!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for workplace guidance and is not about programming as defined by our Help Center topicality section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all i'm not sure there is a "standard" response to this question. It depends on what can your designer / developer do.

In fact there is a third skill required here and it's integration. The integrator is supposed to handle the writing of the design into html & css. But the problem here is that integration is not really developing (for most developer it's boring) and it's not really designing (most designer have trouble integrating their design).

You should first know if one of them is able to do that efficiently.

If it's your designer who is supposed to do that, you just have to tell him to do the integration of the design, he has all the assets.

If it's your developper, you should ask your designer for a global (svg or psd) of the design and to export all the assets he used (icon, font, img, background etc).

if none of them can do the integration, well you'll need a third person.

I hope that helps,
Though there are probably other ways of dealing with this

Comment: I'd like to add that the person that designs **usually** doesn't have the skillset to efficiently integrate the design through HTML and CSS, partially due to growing complexity of RWD and the amount of time it takes to get the hang of something like `flexbox` if you're not used to doing things like this.